# VB.NET Incorporate Alt+Window+Drag into Form

Tags: vb.net, window, drag, windows-messages

I know this would work If I wasn't using a web browser filling up my form.

```
Dim drag As Boolean
Dim mousex As Integer
Dim mousey As Integer

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    '--- Alter the return value of WM_NCHITTEST when the ALT key is down
    If m.Msg = &H84 AndAlso (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Alt) <> 0 Then
        '--- Turn HTCLIENT into HTCAPTION
        If m.Result = 1 Then m.Result = 2
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        drag = True
        mousex = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left
        mousey = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top
    End If

    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 2500
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If drag Then
        Me.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
        Me.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - mousex
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    drag = False
End Sub
```

However I found a program for Windows that has that Linux Alt+Drag window functionality called [AltWindowDrag](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/get-the-linux-altwindow-drag-functionality-in-windows/) I know I can use Process.Start to run the program as I did below...

```
Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\AltWindowDrag\AltWindowDrag.exe")
```

However the problem with this is when I close my app, AltWindowDrag is still running. Anyway I can have AltWindowDrag close when my form closes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT!**

A dude on another forum helped me out with this, so for others that are experiencing the same problem. Here's the code.

```
Dim proc As Process

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    proc = Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\AltWindowDrag\AltWindowDrag.exe")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    If Not proc Is Nothing Then

        If Not proc.HasExited Then

            proc.Kill()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should move your solution to an answer, and probably accept it, if it is the solution you used.

Comment: I already did that two days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a pretty simple trick, Windows asks your app what was clicked when the mouse goes down.  You can simply lie and tell it that the caption bar was clicked instead of the client area.  Which makes Windows automatically move the window when you move the mouse.  Paste this code into your form class:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    '--- Alter the return value of WM_NCHITTEST when the ALT key is down
    If m.Msg = &H84 AndAlso (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Alt) <> 0 Then
        '--- Turn HTCLIENT into HTCAPTION
        If m.Result = 1 Then m.Result = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I feel really dumb, everything looks correct. Maybe I didn't import something, lack of sleep. idk what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Nothing needs to be imported.  I can't guess at a problem without an error message.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, it just won't drag by alt+drag, or click+drag without titlebar.

Comment: Anyway I can send you the project?

Comment: Well, it's Sunday, what the heck.  Post it to a file sharing service.  Use Build + Clean first.

Comment: Thanks! Here you go - http://www.mediafire.com/?s4a0fkq26uh4sel | The reason why I'm going for Alt+Drag is so if there's a drawing app added in (ex. index.html) I don't want the form to drag when the user's trying to draw lol

Comment: You've got the entire form filled with a WebBrowser.  There's no part of the form left to click on but the border and captions.  So you'll always click the browser.  It has its own mouse handling that you can't intercept, it produces DOM events.  This isn't going to work.